# Difference between re.split(" ", string) and re.split("\s+", string)?

Tags: python, split, python-re

I'm currently studying regular expressions and have come across an inquiry.
So the title of the question is what I'm trying to find out. I thought since `\s` represents a white space, `re.split(" ", string)` and `re.split("\s+", string)` would give out same values, as shown next:

```py
>>> import re
>>> a = re.split(" ", "Why is this wrong")
>>> a
["Why", "is", "this", "wrong"]
```

```py
>>> import re
>>> a = re.split("\s+", "Why is this wrong")
>>> a
["Why", "is", "this", "wrong"]
```

These two give out the same answers so I thought that they were the same thing. However, it turns out that these are different. In what case would it be different? And what am I missing here that is blinding me?

Comment: `"\s+"` represents one or more of **any** whitespace, including `" ", "\t", "\n"` and a couple more. `" "` is just  a single space character.

Comment: @schwobaseggl so `\s` can also represent more than just `" "` and can express `Enter (which is equal to \n)`, or `"  ", with two space characters`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This only look similar based on your example.

A split on `' '` (a single space) does exactly that - it splits on a single space. Consecutive spaces will lead to empty "matches" when you split.

A split on `'\s+'` will also split on multiple occurences of those characters and it includes other whitespaces then "pure spaces":

```
import re

a = re.split(" ", "Why    is this  \t \t  wrong")
b = re.split("\s+", "Why    is this  \t \t  wrong")

print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
# re.split(" ",data)
['Why', '', '', '', 'is', 'this', '', '\t', '\t', '', 'wrong']

# re.split("\s+",data)
['Why', 'is', 'this', 'wrong']
```

Documentation:

> **\s**
> Matches any whitespace character; this is equivalent to the class `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`.  (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#matching-characters)

Answer (score 4):

It means about space characters. `'\s'` is split with any whitespaces characters(`\b, \t, \n, \a, \r` etc.). `'+'` is if it's following whitespaces. For example "    \n   \r    \t \v". In my opinion, if you need to use directly string operations for separation, you should use `my_string.split()` like standart methods. Otherwise you should you regex. Because regex engine has a cost and developer should be able to predict that.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the code you posted, the general idea of it is there is not much of a difference of the two (in terms of its goal), both are going to output this.

```
["Why", "is", "this", "wrong"]
```

The difference is just... I would say the **WAY** on how you are going to `split` the string. In this case the first one is using the `.split()` built-in method in a `str` object, the second one is using the `.split()` function from `re`.

Now this one `re.split(" ", "Why is this wrong")` just splits the string base on this character right here `" "` your first parameter or argument

Now this one `re.split("\s+", "Why is this wrong")` splits your string based on this regular expression `\s+`.

Take note that `" "` is not the same as `\s+`. This `\s+` has more like a meaning on what it is & the `" "` is just basically a `str`. You can find out more about regex [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

`\s+` -> `Returns a match where the string contains a white space character`

I should also say that if you want to `split` a string based on not just a `string` or you want to have it more like a pattern? Then [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) is for you.